# How to prove pairwise independence of a family of hash functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, hash-function, universal-property

I want to prove pairwise independence of a family of hash functions, but I don't know where to start.

Given the family of hash functions:

H with h(x) = a * x + b (mod M).

( Say h: U -> V, then: M is a prime and M >= IUI )

So how do I show that the family is pairwise independent. The definition is: The probability that h(u1) = v1 AND h(u2) = v2 is 1/M^2.

I can imagine that the solution has something to do with the modulo ring but I don't know how to get there.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have $h(x) = a x + b \pmod{M}$.

Since M is prime, it follows from [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) that $a x + b$ has at most one solution modulo $m$. Therefore, for a fixed $a$ and $b$, each $x$ will be mapped to a different number in the range $[0 ... M-1]$, and hence, the probability of a specific $x$ to equal one specific element in this range is $1/M$. The logic is the same for $y$. So, the probability that $x$ is equal to one specific value $i$ and $y$ is equal to another specific value $j$ ($i$ can equal $j$) in the range $[0 ... M-1] = \frac{1}{M} \cdot \frac{1}{M} = \frac{1}{M^2}$, which is what is required to be shown.

I hope this helps.